# Labels near coordinates using Tikz

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I searched for over2 hours now and did not find a way to get my labels next to my coordinates. I want to have A and B next to my marks, but ******** - it simply does not work and I am too dumb to understand it reading the manual and examples...
I would really appreciate any kind of help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,twoside,BCOR=1.2cm]{scrreprt}
%\documentclass[12pt,achemso]{article}



\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every mark/.append style={mark size=3pt}]
   \begin{axis}
        [
        ,width={\textwidth}
                ,height=5cm
        %,xlabel=Dithiolenliganden
        ,ylabel=Cool Axis
        ,xtick=data,
                ,ymin=145,ymax=154,
                ,ytick={146,148,150,152},
                %,nodes near coords
                %,meta=label
                %,nodes near coords style={anchor=west,}
                ,xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E}
        ]
                \addplot+[only marks,red,solid,fill=red,mark=diamond
                            ] 
                coordinates
        {
                (0,150.7) %[A]
                (1,148.6) %[A] 
                (2,146.5) %[B] 
                (3,148.4) %[B] 
                (4,150.3)} %[B]
                ;
            
            
                \addplot+[only marks,blue,mark=x] coordinates
        {
                (0,153.3) %[A]
                (1,150.3) %[A] 
                (2,148.5) %[B] 
                (3,151.6) %[A] 
                (4,151.9)} %[B]
                ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end figure
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want to obtain. Can you explain more about `have A and B next to my marks` such as providing a hand-drawing picture?

Answer (score 1):

When you add `nodes near coords`, `pgfplots` will by default place the y-value in a node next to the plotted point. So in addition you need to tell `pgfplots` what it should add in the nodes, which is done using the `point meta` key.

When you provide the text directly in the list of coordinates, e.g.

```
(0,150.7) [A]
```

you need to add `point meta=explicit symbolic` to the `axis` options. `explicit` means that the "point meta", i.e. the text in the nodes, are in the data stream, while `symbolic` means that the text should *not* be parsed and printed as a number. In other words, if your labels are text, use `explicit symbolic`.  The other options for `point meta` are listed in the `pgfplots` manual, section 4.8.2 *User Input Format for Point Meta*.

Complete example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,twoside,BCOR=1.2cm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [every mark/.append style={mark size=3pt}]
   \begin{axis}
        [
        ,width={\textwidth}
                ,height=5cm
        %,xlabel=Dithiolenliganden
        ,ylabel=Cool Axis
        ,xtick=data,
                ,ymin=145,ymax=155, % <-- increased ymax a bit to make room for the labels
                ,ytick distance=2,  % <-- ytick every 2 units
                ,nodes near coords
                ,xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E}
                ,point meta=explicit symbolic
        ]
                \addplot+[only marks,red,solid,fill=red,mark=diamond
                            ] 
                coordinates
        {
                (0,150.7) [A]
                (1,148.6) [A] 
                (2,146.5) [B] 
                (3,148.4) [B] 
                (4,150.3) [B]
                } % <-- in your code this bracket was before the last [B]
                ;
            
            
                \addplot+[only marks,blue,mark=x] coordinates
        {
                (0,153.3) [A]
                (1,150.3) [A] 
                (2,148.5) [B] 
                (3,151.6) [A] 
                (4,151.9) [B]
                }
                ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```